# Accesing the characters two by two

Tags: c++

```
int getFirstValue(string number){
    int result; //holds the converted value
    int total = 0; //holds the sum
    int count = 1;
    // iterate through every character in the string
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < number.length(); i++){  
        if (count % 2 == 0){
            result = number[i] - '0'; //convert the character into an int
            result *= 2; //multiply the value by 2
            total += result; // assign it to total
            ++count; //increment count
        }
    }
    return total; //return the sum
}
```

I want to calculate the sum of every two digits multiplied by two. I don't know how to iterate through a number so I chose to enter it as a string then convert the digits. When I try it with every digit it works just fine but when I use the count variable it returns 0. Maybe it's a dumb question but I can't figure it out. What is wrong?

Comment: Are you aware that the sum of every two digits multiplied by 2 is the same as the sum of every digit multiplied by two? Or are you trying to do like 15 * 2 + 32 * 2 instead of 1*2 + 5*2 + 3*2 + 2*2

Comment: You may use `i += 2` to advance 2 by 2.

Comment: @Jarod42 How have I not think of that. I'm so stupid. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean "every other" digit, or are you trying to take two digits at a time as a single value (10 <= x <= 99)? Your code looks like it's mostly doing the first option.

Comment: @sharth I mean just 5*2 + 2*2. My english is not so good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `count` variable will only be incremented at the end of the `if (count % 2 == 0)` statement. As `count = 1` before the loop, the condition `count % 2 == 0` will never be verified and `total` will stay at 0 until the end.

You should rather increment `count` at every iteration:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < number.length(); i++){  
    if (count % 2 == 0){
        result = number[i] - '0'; //convert the character into an int
        result *= 2; //multiply the value by 2
        total += result; // assign it to total
    }
    ++count; // HERE
}
```

Notice that then, `count` will always be equal to `i+1`.

Answer (score 0):

Following may help (I am not sure which digits you want to sums i.e unity, hundred, ...)

```
int sum(int n)
{
    int res = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        res += n % 10;
        n /= 100;
    }
    return 2 * res;
}

int sum(const std::string& n)
{
    int res = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n.size(); i += 2) {
        res += *(n.rbegin() + i) - '0';
    }
    return 2 * res;
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/Z1mcPk).